# Сбор мусора в базе

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Две модели связаны отношением *один ко многим*, если удалить этот самый ***один*** - понятно, что все ***многие*** удалятся, если не указать `WillCascadeOnDelete(false)`.  Но мне нужна обратная задача, чтобы автоматически удалился  ***один*** когда все ***много*** зависящие от него удалятся.

Answer (score 0):

На ум приходит повесить какой-нибудь триггер на БД, который будет проверять при удалении **многих** на **единственный** элемент ничего не ссылается => грохается следом.

Можно сделать JOB, который будет чекать время от времени элементы и удалять "**мусор**".

Answer (score 0):

Эта задача очень органично решается в рамках `DDD`. Каждая зависимая сущность должна генерировать соответствующее событие при своем удалении. На уровне приложения должен быть обработчик, заинтересованный в этих событиях. При получении такого события, обработчик достает из базы соответствующую сущность от которой все зависят и уменьшает у нее количество зависимых. Если количество зависимых стало равно нулю, то обработчик удаляет основную сущность. В качестве средства рассылки событий можно использовать [MediatR](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR). Если у вас контекст базы данных существует в рамках запроса, то вы заодно получите консистентность и транзакционность. Если нет, то согласованность в конечном итоге. В качестве недостатка можно отметить большее количество кода, по сравнению с триггером в базе. Основное преимущество - бизнес логика не просочится в базу данных.